# Using a Notification Extension causes issue with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Notification Extension in my app. However, when I build my app it conflicts with the pod `FBSDKLoginKit`. It gives me the following error in the FBSDKCoreKit:

`'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.`

My Podfile looks like this (I've missed out irrelevant pods):

```
workspace 'MyApp'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  project 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'

  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
  end
end
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: From what I understand, you're calling the 'sharedApplication' in a non-controller view class. So it has nothing todo with your podfile afaik. Try inheriting the extension to a UIViewController for testing purposes and try again.

Comment: The error occurs in Facebook's `FBSDKLoginKit` framework, imported using Cocoapods. I don't have control over this code.

Comment: Check this link. It might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225213/uiapplication-sharedapplication-not-available

Answer (score 1):

Move your `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` target out of your main target in your Podfile. Don't forget to also define `use_frameworks!` in it!

```
workspace 'MyApp'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  project 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end
```

`pod install`, Clean and Build and that should do the trick