# How to define pod file for iOS Extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When defining my Podfile as below, and then building my app with my extension I get a build error in the DKImagePickerController framework with an error similar to this: [Error "'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)...." when compiling after pod update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031071/error-sharedapplication-is-unavailable-not-available-on-ios-app-extension)

As you can see I have not included the DKImagePickerController framework in my extension target in my Podfile, so I'm wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
 platform :ios, '10.0'
    def base_pods
      pod 'Firebase/Core'
      pod 'Firebase/Auth'
      pod 'DKImagePickerController', '~> 3.4.0'
      ...
      pod 'SAMKeychain'
    end

target 'MyApp' do

  use_frameworks!
  base_pods

  target 'MyAppExtension' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'SAMKeychain'
  end

  target 'MyAppUnitTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'Firebase'
        pod 'FirebaseAuth'
        pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
  end
end
```

**Update**

I appreciate that I am getting the error due to an API being unavailable, what I am trying to figure out is how to avoid it. My suspicion is on my podfile, hence my question :)

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, so for anyone else finding this thread, I was able to solve the problem by creating two top-level targets instead of using a nested target.

```
target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Eureka', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'ChameleonFramework', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'SharedPod', '~>1.0'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'MyApp Today' do
  use_frameworks!
  # inherit! :none
  # Pods for MyApp Today
  pod 'SharedPod', '~>1.0'
end
```

To get a clean start I then ran...

```
pod deintegrate
-- Then cleaned out the project file in XCode
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few API's which are unavailable in App Extension's. One of them is `UIApplication`. The framework developer has to make sure this never happens. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6

Comment: Sachin, I appreciate that, I should have made it clearer that I know why the error is occuring. Iøm trying to figure out how to avoid this error

Comment: You need to check with the DKImagePickerController framework developers. They need to duplicate the original scheme and then add the source with the pre-processor macro which will avoid compiling the App extension unavailable API's. This leads to duplication of code, read http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.38/#target-deduplication

Comment: But I dont want to include that framework in my target. That's the whole point. Why is it even complaining about it when it's not specified as a dependancy in my podfile?

Comment: Then I think you are compiling the class which uses the DKImagePickerController in the App Extension.